Two peaks of one pure compound in GCMS?
Analyzed compound: imidacloprid
Conditions:
Column DB-5 30/0.32/0.25
Oven temperature: 30 or 60 (depends on DCM or ACN solvent respectively) - 300 (with 90 sec and 5 min holding time respectively) with different ramp rate.
Splitless injection, purge time flow 90 sec, flow rate 1ml/min, carrier gas He.
As a basis Giddings approximation was used.
Temperature MS source 230C, quad 150C, scan mode.
Automatic type injection with double rinsing before and after injection.
Septum, gold seal etc. were changed before injections as well as liner (splitless liner).
There were different types of inlet/aux temperature, injection volume and concentration.
First try (attached images 1 and 2)
10C/min ramp rate
concentration 0.24 mg/ml
1 mkl injection volume, DCM solution
Inlet, AUX temperature 230C
As we can see, there are two peaks, that can be determined as imidacloprid (99, 126, 211 characterized ions) at 16.28 and 19.20. The latter peak is also huge and abnormally broadened.
Because a decomposition temperature for imidacloprid is near 230C I decided that this was an exposure of partial decomposition. So I decreased inlet and AUX temperatures (albeit retention temperature was near 250C) to 200C to avoid decomposition.


Second try (attached images 3 and 4)
20 C/min ramp rate
concentration 0.11 mg/ml
1mkl injection volume, ACN solution
Inlet, AUX temperature 200C
We still can observe two peaks with specific ions (16.3 and 19.2 min). After that I decided to increase the temperature for inlet and aux to see what would happen.


Third try (attached images 5 and 6)
30 C/min ramp rate
concentration 0.11 mg/ml
1mkl injection volume, ACN solution
Inlet, AUX temperature 280C
Peak at 8.3 looks much better than at lower inlet temperatures. Thale area of first peak increased significantly. But there us still the second peak at 9.2 with the same ions.
I concluded that that might be evidence of too concentrated solution and this particular compound requires high temperatures to be detected despite of substantially lower decomposition temperature.


Final try (attached images 7 and 8)
Conditions stayed the same as for previous try except of injection volume (0.2mkl)
Generally nothing changed. We still have two peaks with the same ions.


Because I'm not proficient in GCMS I'd like to ask kindly, could someone, please, explain:

what has happened, why we observe two peaks (is the issue in low temperature or over-concentrated solution or in column etc) instead of one peak
does increasing temperature on MS source make sense (for all tries it was 230)?
what is correlation between decomposition temperature and fact that at higher temperatures we can observe imidacloprid better?

I'll appreciate any help from anyone, who is aware of GCMS troubleshooting.
P.S. another analysis for fludioxonil showed great results on that column without any issues and additional peaks.

First. Please give us the formula of the solute, and of the solvent, plus the impurities. I don't know the chemistry of imidacloprid and fludioxonil. But I can comment a bit your measurements. Your first image shows three thin peaks at 22.8, 23.8 and 26, plus a rather broad peak at 28. So there are three pure substances in small amount, plus a huge signal at 28. Have you measured the surface of these peaks ? It looks as if the broad peak at 28 is the solvent. Is it right? Have you calculated the retention indexes of these thin peaks ? This index may help you know the formula of the thin peaks,

What is the temperature between the column outlet and the MS source (don't remember what the parameter is called, is it AUX?). You don't want you material to get stuck between GC and MS.

I highlighted the peaks on the chromatograms, which contain ions associated with imidacloprid. All other peaks contain other ions, that's why they can be ignored. Unfortunately, retention time is not a reliable source for absolute detection and determination (but good enough as relative measurement). There is no solvent peak on any chromatogram (these are the stretch of chromatograms ending), where we can observe only less voltage compounds.

Imidacloprid and fludioxonil are easy to find in the google. They have a little bit complicated chemical structure that is easier to search than to enclose here

I wrote about all solvents and temperatures I'd used. I had DCM and ACN as solvents and AUX temperatures 200, 230, 280. Higher temperatures helped to better peak shapes but I didn't get rid of the second broadened peak.

I appreciate all the help. Supposedly someone has hands-on experience with GC troubleshooting so he could reveal the source of issue.
